# Red5 and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, red5

I want setup red5chatv2.1 but Eclipse(juno) Java compiler say error.

The import `org.red5.server.api.ScopeUtils` cannot be resolved !

I have red5 1.0.0, java 7.0

```
package chat;

import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IClient;
import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.Red5;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IServiceCapableConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.so.ISharedObject;
import org.red5.server.api.ScopeUtils;
import org.red5.server.api.so.ISharedObjectService;
import org.red5.server.api.*;
import org.red5.server.api.scheduling.*;
import org.red5.samples.components.ClientManager;
import org.red5.server.api.service.ServiceUtils;
import org.red5.server.api.service.*;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IPendingServiceCallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-Zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

As I am facing errors, I request you to contribute in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments  using new version netbeans, jdk for new version glassfish server(3.x).

Arumugam A.V